# Why is & being converted to &amp;amp?

Tags: php, file, csv

```
$file="csv.php?task=whovotedwho&election=7"; 
$filename = "whovotedwho-election7.csv"; 

if (file_exists("trash.png")) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.($filename).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("trash.png"));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    } else { echo "file does not exist"; }
```

I get this result in the csv that downloads.

[image: double amp in code]

Comment: it looks like you have several extensions (like x-debug) installed, one of them has bug and performs double html encoding

Comment: Is there a `readfile` equivalent for php files?

Comment: You're not downloading the CSV file. Look at what you got, it's an error message saying that `readfile()` failed.

Comment: @Andrew I changed my code to use `file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/csv.php?task=whovo‌​tedwho&election=7")` but now it's adding garbage to my query. http://i.imgur.com/2WaXOpd.png

Comment: @Andrew If the `url_fopen` option is enabled, all file-reading functions work with URLs, including `readfile()`.

Comment: Why do you use `filesize("trash.png")`? What does that have to do with the size of the CSV file being downloaded?

Comment: As Barmar mentioned, you can use `readfile` with the full url instead. I don't understand why you get that error. It looks like some weird character encoding issue.

Comment: I tried to get the file size of the php file which generates the csv I want to export, but as I was using `readfile`, that wasn't working, so I changed it to a file I know exists and will work, and will plan on putting it back to how it should be later on. ;)

Comment: Not an answer, but why not make csv.php into a class, then include this class in your current PHP file, and do something like, `$csv = new CSV('whovotedwho', 7); $csv->save('whovotedwho-election7.csv');` Would be much more efficient than sending an HTTP request to your own server.

Comment: I have a new problem @Andrew `$file="csv.php?task=whovotedwho&election=7"; include($file);` When I include the `$file` variable, the `&` is converted to `&amp;`

Comment: You can't pass a url with query string parameters to `include`. Did you try `readfile("http://www.example.com/csv.php?task=whovotedwho&election=7")`

Comment: I found a way to solve my problem by using `include` and `$_REQUEST` using your answer that you deleted. You can't use query strings on `readfile` either.

Comment: cool, I'm glad it worked for you. I'm puzzled how it worked. Maybe you can post a self-answer showing how you fixed it.

Comment: I fixed it using your answer that you deleted.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/desbest/c7cccaeeca6aa64818469686c6983896

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
$file="csv.php?task=whovotedwho&election=7";
```

It's not a full/absolute url like `http://example.com/csv.php...`, so when readfile() kicks in, it's doing a **LOCAL** file request, and looking for a file whose name is literally `csv.php?tasketc...` It's **NOT** doing an http request - it can't. you didn't provide a protocol, or a host, for that http request to get sent TO.

PHP is not like your browser, where something like `<img src=kittens.jpg>` is internally translated into `<img src="http://example.com/kittens.jpg">`.

And frankly, even if you had a full URL there, it's VERY painful to do so - you're already executing code on the exact SAME server you'd be doing the http request so, so it's like hopping in your car and driving 500 miles around the city, just so you could park 1 foot to the left of where you started out on.

And what you're seing in your errors is the raw HTML. Since your filename has `&` in it, it has to get HTML-encoded so it appears as a literal `&` in the output, and isn't RENDERED as an html entity.